# Building a generated project as a Grunt Task

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, yeoman

I'm using Yeoman to generate a project.  This gen'd project includes a Gruntfile with a `build` task.

As part of my generator's tests I'd like to ensure that a generated project builds out of the box.

How can I invoke "grunt build" programmatically?

The first approach that comes to mind is to spawn a new process, and capture it's exit code.

Is there a more elegant way to accomplish this with Grunt?

Answer (score 0):

In a task you can do:

```
grunt.task.run('build');
```

To queue the build task to run after the current one.

If you're not actually in your `Gruntfile.js` you can do:

```
var grunt = require('grunt');
grunt.tasks(['build']);
```

Comment: Thanks Stuart,
I'm actually looking for a way to invoke the generated grunt file as a test.

Currently the generator test suite creates a new project, and asserts that all the necessary files have indeed been created.

In addition, I'd like to assert that the generated project builds. (As a test that's part of the generator, not the generated project)